# What printer model have I to choose for Toshiba e-Studio 2330c?

Tags: drivers, printing

I'm unable to find this model in the list of available Toshiba models.
Would you mind telling me a compatible one?

Answer (score 1):

The [Toshiba](http://www.eid.toshiba.com.au/n_driver_es4520c.asp) websites indicate that this printer is compatible with CUPS, which should already be on your system. Open your browser, goto the website `http://localhost:631/`and attempt to add the printer from those pages.

Comment: The behaviour is the same of the printer configuration provided by Ubuntu (and I think the printer configuration is more simple than CUPS pages, IMHO). The problem remains: there-s no model 2330c in the list of models of Toshiba manifacturer...

Comment: If you choose "Toshiba e-Studio 4520c Foomatic/pxlcolor" from the list it seems to work.  I was tipped off to this because when I downloaded the CUPS filter for this printer from Toshiba's site the file name was TOSHIBA_EST4520C_CUPS.gz.  I'm using CUPS 2.2.8.

Answer (score 1):

the Toshiba site seams to indicate that drivers are interchangeable

http://www.estudio.com.sg/download_2330c2820c3520c4520c.aspx

Comment: This link is broken.  But if I can guess the original intent of this answer and the link, it is to indicate that you want to select e-Studio 4520c from the list of drivers because it works for the 2330c as well.